# How to show image in my Cocoapod from Readme.md file?

Tags: github, cocoapods, markdown, readme

I have created a Cocoapod - [RPUpdatingLabelFramework](https://cocoapods.org/pods/RPUpdatingLabelFramework) and added a README.md file. I have added a link (relative path) to an image (part of my repository) in the Readme.md file. When I commit & push my repository to Github - [raunakp/RPUpdatingLabel](https://github.com/raunakp/RPUpdatingLabel), I can see the image in Github's rendering of my README.md file.

However, I don't see the image in Cocoapod's rendering of my README.md file.

Please check my README.md file at https://github.com/raunakp/RPUpdatingLabel/blob/master/README.md and help me understand what I am doing wrong here?

I want the image to be shown in my Cocoapods description page as well.

Answer (score 1):

You used the relative path `screenshot1.png` for the image file. It works for the same repository, but when you try it on a different repository, the image can't be loaded.

See here, the cocoapods repo is trying to get the image from `https://cocoapods.org/pods/screenshot1.png`, which does not reflect any image:

[image: Cocoapods image source]

You need to replace `src="screenshot1.png"` with `src="https://github.com/raunakp/RPUpdatingLabel/blob/master/screenshot1.png"` or any absolute path with this image stored in your `README.md` file.

Comment: Take a look at the Readme file of this repository: https://cocoapods.org/pods/RPBorderlessSegmentedControl
It still uses relative path for image and renders correctly on cocoapod